# Конвертировать координаты ЕГРН в географические координаты

Tags: python

Попытался сам хоть немного разобраться, но уже "поплыл" и запутался в край. Есть координаты из выписок/КПТ ЕГРН по типу таких - "**x 536359.03**" и "**y 2205836.12**". Нашел [**сайт**](https://egrp365.org/gps-calculator/), который переводит эти координаты в географические. По данным с сайта, географические координаты "Ш **56.37917**" и "**Д 43.83337**" и координаты получились верными. Так как таких координат из ЕГРН у меня в дальнейшем будет много, хотел сделать в Python.

Нашел систему координат, которые в ЕГРН, называется "**МСК-52 зона 2 Нижегородская область [MB:6335202]**" (путем проб и ошибок...) и его "**PROJ.4**" на [**сайте**](https://terraingis.ru/msk-52.html) - "**+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=44.55 +k=1 +x_0=2250000 +y_0=-5714743.504 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.57,-140.95,-79.8,0,0.35,0.79,-0.22 +units=m +no_defs**". Выяснил,что  "**PROJ.4**", который выше указал, это по ГОСТ 51794-2008 (по листал документацию... там пипец) и он [**отменен**](https://gis-lab.info/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16901), сейчас как понял ГОСТ 32453-2013, для него "**PROJ.4**" не нашел, а писать его по ГОСТ 32453-2013, черт ногу сломит...

Пробовал на бум подобрать на [**сайте**](https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/) "**PROJ.4**", на сайте в 1 окно (Ввод системы координат / проекция) ввел вышенаписанный "**PROJ.4**", во 2 окно подбирал "**PROJ.4**" по Российской федерации, но я так думаю не все так просто.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот мой код:

```py
import pyproj
# Создаем объект проекции для системы координат Гаусса-Крюгера
proj_gk = pyproj.Proj("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=45 +k=1 +x_0=5500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.92,-141.27,-80.9,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

# МСК-52 Нижегородская область
proj_msk52 = pyproj.Proj("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=44.55 +k=1 +x_0=2250000 +y_0=-5714743.504 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.57,-140.95,-79.8,0,0.35,0.79,-0.22 +units=m +no_defs")

# Создаем объект проекции для географических координат (широта, долгота)
proj_geo = pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

# Задаем координаты в системе Гаусса-Крюгера
x = 536359.03
y = 2205836.12

# Производим преобразование координат из системы Гаусса-Крюгера в МСК-52 Нижегородская область
x_msk52, y_msk52 = pyproj.transform(proj_gk, proj_msk52, x, y)

# Производим преобразование координат из МСК-52 Нижегородская область в географические координаты
lon, lat = pyproj.transform(proj_msk52, proj_geo, x_msk52, y_msk52)

print("Широта: ", lat)
print("Долгота: ", lon)
```

Comment: Есть сайт https://dadata.ru. Не возьмусь утверждать с гарантией, но кажется, что он может быть Вам полезен

Comment: @Namerek, да, про этот сайт знаю, но там можно геокодировать адрес в географические координаты и наоборот. тут нужно конвертировать (как я понимаю...) координаты из одной плоскости в местной системе координат в географические. наверно правильно написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе... для меня эта задача (в Python) не решаема. но нашел хороший конвертер, можно всю КПТ туда загнать и выгрузить. Вот ссылка на [сайт](https://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80.%D1%80%D1%84/ws/csc/). Можно и закрыть тему на этом

Answer (score 2):

нашел статью [**сайт**](https://habr.com/ru/articles/521910/). Нашел комментарий пользователя:

> Цитата:
> Задача перехода от «плоской системы координат» к WGS84 делится на две части — сначала переход от проекции к той системе координат из которой она получена, а потом уже переход из той системы координат к WGS84 (если изначальная система координат была иной). - SpiderEkb

Написал вот такой код:

```html
import pyproj

x = 536359.03
y = 2205836.12

# МСК-52 зона 2 Нижегородская область
proj_msk_52 = pyproj.Proj('+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=44.55 +k=1 +x_0=2250000 +y_0=-5714743.504 +ellps=krass +towgs84=23.57,-140.95,-79.8,0,0.35,0.79,-0.22 +units=m +no_defs')
lon, lat = proj_msk_52(x, y, inverse=True)
# WGS84
proj_wgs84 = pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs')
# из МСК-52 в WGS84
lon, lat = pyproj.transform(proj_msk_52, proj_wgs84, lon, lat)
print(lat)
print(lon)
```

Все равно выдает координаты левые "**47.475971502889465 14.519519023494398**", а нужно получить "**Ш 56.37917**" и "**Д 43.83337**". Все таки, чувство такое, что ошибка в **proj_msk_52**, указан код "PROJ.4" по ГОСТ 51794-2008, а нужно ГОСТ 32453-2013